# I want to write spring boot code to fetch data from mongoDB with condition

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am able to fetch data from MongoDB using the following code but I want to expose that data from CommandLineRunner runner to other class.

```
@Repository
public interface ToolsDao extends MongoRepository< Tools, String> {
     public List<Tools> findByRegistries_active(boolean active);
}
```

Also, I have written class as with getters and setters with constructors.

```
public class Tools{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private List<Registries> registries;
```

And For registries I have,

```
public class Registries {

    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String secret;
    private boolean active;
```

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner runner(ToolsDao toolsDao) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            Registries activeRegistry = null;
            Iterable<Tools> toolsList= toolsDao.findByRegistries_active(true);
            System.out.println("Configuration : ");

            for (Tools tools : toolsList) {
                for (Registries registry : config.getRegistries()) {
                    if(registry.getActive()) {
                        activeRegistry = registry;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("active registry name is " + activeRegistry.getName());
            System.out.println("active registry url " + activeRegistry.getRegistryUrl());

        }
    };
}
```

I am getting output in the above function but if I want to use in any other function then It is giving null values.

```
public class RegistryController2 {
@Autowired
ToolsDao toolsDao;
public Registries getData() {
    Registries activeRegistry = null;
    Iterable<Tools> personList = toolsDao.findByRegistries_active(true);
    System.out.println("Configuration : ");

    for (Tools tools : toolsList) {
        for (Registries registry : tools.getRegistries()) {
            if(registry.getActive()) {
                activeRegistry = registry;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("active registry name is " + activeRegistry.getName());
    System.out.println("active registry url " + activeRegistry.getRegistryUrl());
}
```

MongoDB database :

```
Given below is MongoDB Collection from database test. and collection name is switchrepo.

"_id" : "1234567890",
    "type" : "toolss",
    "registreis" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "url" : "test1",
            "secret" : "secret",
            "active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test2",
            "url" : "test12",
            "secret" : "secret2",
            "active" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is `ToolsConfig` you autowire in `RegistryController2`? You should use `ToolsDao` instead. Also, is the `RegistryController2` already anotated with `@Service` or `@Component`?

Comment: Updated with changes suggested by you. Yes, RegistryController2 is annotated with  ```@Service```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.controller.RegistryController2.getData(RegistryController2.java:23)
 at com.example.JavaMongoApplication.main(JavaMongoApplication.java:23)



This is error I am getting